# passing an image from a list view to another activity

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to pass an image from a list view to another activity when the list item is clicked. I have managed to figure out how to get the text data from the list item but have been stuck on how to pass the image from the list to the intended activity. The data is stored in an array that contains the image as a resource. I know its probably something trivial that I am missing but I have tried to get it to work multiple ways and looked at multiple tutorials and have not been able to resolve the issue.

This is my code for the activity where I have the array declared and the on item click listener declared.

```
    package com.example.android.musicplayer69;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArtistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String KEY_SONG = "KEY_SONG";
    public static final String KEY_ARTIST = "KEY_ARTIST";





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        ArrayList<Song> song = new ArrayList<Song>();


        /** words.add("one")*/

        song.add(new Song("Last Night", "The Strokes", "Is this 
It",R.drawable.albumcover));
        song.add(new Song("Golden Fleeces", "Israel Nash", 
"Lifted",R.drawable.play));
        song.add(new Song("Heavy, California", "Jungle", "Heavy 
California",R.drawable.albumcover));
        song.add(new Song("Grow Up", "Boiler", "Grow 
Up",R.drawable.albumcover));
        song.add(new Song("The Ballad of the Costa Concordia", "Car Seat 
Head Rest", "Teens of Denial",R.drawable.albumcover));
        song.add(new Song("Leaving", "Bass Drum of Death", "Just 
Business",R.drawable.albumcover));
        song.add(new Song("Creature Comfort", "Woods", "City Sun Eater in 
the River of Light",R.drawable.albumcover));
        song.add(new Song("Summer with Phill", "Dead Ghost", "Can't Get 
No",R.drawable.albumcover));
        song.add(new Song("Night Ride", "The Growlers", "Night 
Ride",R.drawable.albumcover));


        final SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(this, song);

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        // When listView item is clicked, item data is sent to new activity
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
position, long id) {
                Song item = adapter.getItem(position);

                Intent nowPlaying = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
MainActivity.class);
                nowPlaying.putExtra(KEY_SONG, item.getmSong());
                nowPlaying.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, item.getmArtist());
                nowPlaying.putExtra("IMAGE_RES",item.getAlbumArt());



                startActivity(nowPlaying);}
        });


}


}
```

and here is the code for the activity that I am trying to pass the information to.

```
package com.example.android.musicplayer69;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.android.musicplayer69.ArtistActivity.KEY_ARTIST;
import static com.example.android.musicplayer69.ArtistActivity.KEY_SONG;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageSwitcher v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String playingSong = "";
        String playingArtist = "";



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (null != intent) {
            playingSong = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_SONG);
            playingArtist = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);



            {
            }

        }

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        int nowPlayingArt = bundle.getInt("IMAGE_RES");



// Sets data to appropriate TextViews
        TextView playingSongText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Song);
        playingSongText.setText(playingSong);


        TextView playingArtistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Artist);
        playingArtistText.setText(playingArtist);



        ImageView nowPlayingAlbumArt = findViewById(R.id.AlbumCover);
        nowPlayingAlbumArt.setImageResource(nowPlayingArt);




        // Sets activity_main as the layout file
        ImageView menu = findViewById(R.id.home_button);

        // creates button/ sets on click listener for Artist View
        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent menuIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
menuActivity.class);`
                startActivity(menuIntent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

and this is the error that that I am getting from the console:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.musicplayer69, PID: 11885
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.musicplayer69/com.example.android.musicplayer69.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.android.musicplayer69.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your Image into Byte Array. Take a look at example.

**Example (Convert image to Byte Array):**

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

**Example (Pass your Byte Array):**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Example (Get passed data and convert to bitmap):**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw a similar example but i am confused as to where exactly in my code in need to implement this. This also would only apply to one image at  a time I believe but i have multiple images stored in the array that i need to retrieve for each item click.  I will keep trying to see if i can make it work